# Why can't I cast DateTime[] to object[]?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, casting

It seems that I can cast DateTime to object, so why can't I cast array DateTime[] to object[]?  I know this has something to do with value/reference types, but doesn't boxing allow me to do this?

Comment: It is possible, so you must be trying to do it incorrectly.

Comment: @Kirk: Not in C# it isn't. Or in any language on the CLR. There's no such reference conversion.

Comment: @Eric: I misunderstood the question! I meant that you can get a DateTime[] into an object[] (by casting each DateTime to an object), but of course you're correct - the array itself can't be cast.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't convert value type array to params object\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104268/cant-convert-value-type-array-to-params-object)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Array covariance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee207183.aspx) only applies to arrays of reference types.  `DateTime` is a value type so you can't assign a `DateTime[]` to an `object[]` variable.  You'll have to explicitly create an object array and copy the values over.  In other words, create a new array instance of type `object[]`.

There are plenty of ways you can do this.  A simple use of [`CopyTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copyto.aspx) should be enough.

```
DateTime[] x = new DateTime[] { ... };
object[] y = new object[x.Length];
x.CopyTo(y, 0);
```

---

I ran some tests.  Probably not the best way to do it but it should give a good idea of what it would be with a proper profiler.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var dates = new DateTime[5000000];
        for (int i = 0; i < dates.Length; i++)
            dates[i] = now.AddSeconds(i);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            Test("Test1", () =>
            {
                var result = new object[dates.LongLength];
                for (long l = 0; l < result.LongLength; l++)
                    result[l] = dates[l];
                return result;
            });
            Test("Test2", () =>
            {
                var result = new object[dates.LongLength];
                dates.CopyTo(result, 0);
                return result;
            });
            Test("Test3", () =>
            {
                var result = new object[dates.LongLength];
                Array.Copy(dates, result, dates.LongLength);
                return result;
            });
            Test("Test4", () =>
            {
                var result = Array.ConvertAll(dates, d => (object)d);
                return result;
            });
            Test("Test5", () =>
            {
                var result = dates.Cast<object>().ToArray();
                return result;
            });
            Test("Test6", () =>
            {
                var result = dates.Select(d => (object)d).ToArray();
                return result;
            });
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }

    static void Test<T>(string name, Func<T> fn)
    {
        var startMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var result = fn();
        sw.Stop();
        var endMem = GC.GetTotalMemory(false);
        var diff = endMem - startMem;
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\tMem: {1,7}/{2,7} ({3,7})", name, startMem, endMem, diff);
        Console.WriteLine("\tTime: {0,7} ({1,7})", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, sw.ElapsedTicks);
    }
}
```

Specs:
Win7Pro x64, Core2Quad Q9550@2.83GHz, 4GiB DDR2 1066 (PC2-8500)
64-bit build (32-bit is roughly the same, just less memory overall)

```
Test1   Mem: 40086256/200087360 (160001104)
        Time:     444 (1230723)
Test2   Mem: 40091352/200099272 (160007920)
        Time:     751 (2078001)
Test3   Mem: 40091416/200099256 (160007840)
        Time:     800 (2213764)
Test4   Mem: 40091480/200099256 (160007776)
        Time:     490 (1358326)
Test5   Mem: 40091608/300762328 (260670720)
        Time:    1407 (3893922)
Test6   Mem: 40091672/300762328 (260670656)
        Time:     756 (2092566)

Test1   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     515 (1425098)
Test2   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     868 (2404151)
Test3   Mem: 40091736/200099160 (160007424)
        Time:     885 (2448850)
Test4   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     540 (1494429)
Test5   Mem: 40091736/300762240 (260670504)
        Time:    1479 (4093676)
Test6   Mem: 40091736/300762216 (260670480)
        Time:     746 (2065095)

Test1   Mem: 40091736/200099168 (160007432)
        Time:     500 (1383656)
Test2   Mem: 40091736/200099160 (160007424)
        Time:     781 (2162711)
Test3   Mem: 40091736/200099176 (160007440)
        Time:     793 (2194605)
Test4   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     486 (1346549)
Test5   Mem: 40091736/300762232 (260670496)
        Time:    1448 (4008145)
Test6   Mem: 40091736/300762232 (260670496)
        Time:     749 (2075019)

Test1   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     487 (1349320)
Test2   Mem: 40091736/200099176 (160007440)
        Time:     781 (2162729)
Test3   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     800 (2214766)
Test4   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     506 (1400698)
Test5   Mem: 40091736/300762224 (260670488)
        Time:    1436 (3975880)
Test6   Mem: 40091736/300762232 (260670496)
        Time:     743 (2058002)

Test1   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     482 (1335709)
Test2   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     777 (2150719)
Test3   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     793 (2196184)
Test4   Mem: 40091736/200099184 (160007448)
        Time:     493 (1365222)
Test5   Mem: 40091736/300762240 (260670504)
        Time:    1434 (3969530)
Test6   Mem: 40091736/300762232 (260670496)
        Time:     746 (2064278)
```

Interestingly, `ConvertAll()` performs much the same as a plain loop.

Comment: thanks for the explanation and the link!  I had thought the .net 4 covariance work would have covered this scenario but I guess not.

Comment: awesome tests.  This basically says that Array.ConvertAll is EXCELLENT in terms of performance (and only 1 line of code so more readable than Test1 method.

Answer (score 4):

You can't cast `DateTime[]` to `object[]` because it would be unsafe. All arrays of reference types of the same length have the same layout in memory. DateTime is value type, and the array is "flat" (unboxed). You can't safely cast to `object[]` because the layout in memory is incompatible with `object[]`.

Comment: This really isn't the reason. Variance is allowed on arrays for reference types, for example, and equally "unsafe" things are possibly at compile time and will throw at runtime on the assignment.

Comment: @Logan - I'm not following...the "Uh oh" line should work perfectly fine.

Comment: @SFun, the "Uh oh" line would actually be line 3 in the above snippet.

Comment: The example doesn't really illustrate the problem I admit.

Comment: @Anthony- I'm sure I'm missing something...isn't anything assignable to an object.  Why would like 3 fail if it were an array of object?

Comment: @Anthony: Actually it should "Uh oh" on the second line at compile time.  You can't (explicitly) cast arrays of value types to arrays of any other type (nor any other type to arrays of value types) as the compiler should catch that.

Comment: @SFun, because it *really isn't* an array of type object. It's still referencing an array of another type. In this case, a theoretical `DateTime[]` array.

Comment: @Jeff Mercado, I was speaking in terms of my first comment. I apologize for the confusion.

Comment: I've gotten rid of the misleading example and tried to clarify.

Comment: @Jeff: To be picky, you *can* get around compiler restrictions and cast certain arrays of value type to each other. For example, even though the C# compiler will try to stop you, the CLR permits int[] to be converted to uint[]. What the CLR actually requires is that the element types be *assignment compatible*, and int is assignment compatible with uint.

Answer (score 3):

If you've got LINQ available (.NET 3.5+) you can do:

```
DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[3];

dates[0] = new DateTime(2009, 01, 01);
dates[1] = new DateTime(2010, 01, 01);
dates[2] = new DateTime(2011, 01, 01);

object[] dates2 = Array.ConvertAll(dates, d => (object)d);
```

As Jeff pointed out you can also do a similar thing in .NET 2.0 using delegates:

```
object[] dates3 = Array.ConvertAll(dates, 
                        delegate(DateTime d) { return (object)d; });
```

Comment: @Kev - Thoughts on whether Array.ConvertAll is faster than Cast<object>().ToArray()?

Comment: Just so you know, [`Array.ConvertAll()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) is also .NET 2.0 compatible.  Though you probably won't be able to use a lambda in that case.

Comment: @SFun28 - with `Cast<object>().ToArray()` you'd be walking the array twice. Once for the `Cast<object>()` then again for `.ToArray()`. You only walk the array once with `.ConvertAll()`.

Comment: @Kev: Correction, it's walked through only once though it does create two extra enumerators, one for the Cast and one for the ToArray converter.  The Cast is just a generator, it will not copy the results into a new collection, it just generates the casted object as the source is enumerated.  ToArray forces the enumeration putting the results into the array.  All non-converters (i.e., all operations that start with To-) are generators.  There's a difference.

Comment: @Jeff - so perf isn't so bad after all?

Comment: @SFun: It's not terrible, just not as good as allocating the array in the beginning (which `ConvertAll()` can do).  The problem with using `ToArray()` is that it can't determine the length of the source in general.  So like a List, it will start with a fixed size array and add items to it as the source is enumerated.  If it needs to be resized, a new larger array is allocated copying the contents of the older one.  Then in the end, the results are copied to a correctly sized array.

Comment: p.s., Just to clarify my previous comment, I've made a typo.  The functions that are not enumerable converters (i.e., all operations that _doesn't_ start with To-) are generators.  They do not make copies of your collections, they merely pass the values from it's source through as it is enumerated over.

Comment: @Jeff - so essentially everytime I see the LINQ pattern x.Select(...).ToArray() its better (perf POV) to use Array.Converall( x, select statement here) because the latter allocates the full size of the array instead of building-it-up as it enumerates?

Comment: @SFun: Yes.  I did some benchmarking for this for memory and speed.  I'll add that into my answer so you can see the difference.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, you can accomplish this using [Array.Copy()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k4yx47a1.aspx)

```
void Main()
{
    DateTime[] dates = new DateTime[] { new DateTime(2000, 1, 1), new DateTime (2000, 3, 25) };
    object[] objDates = new object[2];
    Array.Copy(dates, objDates, 2);

    foreach (object o in objDates) {
        Console.WriteLine(o);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks!  Also accomplished via LINQ: dates.Cast<object>().ToArray()

Answer (score 0):

Because `DateTime` **is** an `object`, but an array of `DateTime` **isn't** an array of `object`.

Arrays of value types are different than arrays of reference types so these two types of arrays are fundamentally incompatible.  The value type array actually contains the values and the reference type array contains, well, only references.

Answer (score 0):

See the other answers for *why* you cannot do so.

The alternative is to perform a deep copy of the array. Example using LINQ:

```
DateTime[] dates = ...;
object[] objects = dates.Select(d => (object)d).ToArray();
```

Comment: or dates.Cast<object>().ToArray() which is what I'm doing now.

Comment: @SFun28 Oh, yeah, forgot about that one.