# Converting Datatable columns to array of array

Tags: c#, arrays, highcharts

Having an DataView `tmp`, I need to create from two columns of `tmp` an array of array (probably this is not the correct term in c#, I'm new to it) to be passed to DotNet.Highcharts. The final structure should be something like:

```
 [[5, 2], [6, 3], [8, 2]]
```

First, I used this code:

```
Object[] result = new object[tmp.Count];
result = tmp.Table
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => new Object[] { row.Field<DateTime>("DATE"),
                                            Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<string>("VALUE"))})
            .ToArray();
```

The problem came when I try to substitute an element of `result` with a `Point` (to define custom marker e.g.):

```
if (something[k] == "TRUE") // if for a given row a generic condition is true
{
    result[k] = new DotNet.Highcharts.Options.Point
    {
        X = Tools.GetTotalMilliseconds((DateTime)tmp[k].Row["DATE"]),
        Y = Convert.ToInt32(tmp[k].Row["VALUE"]),
        Marker = new PlotOptionsSeriesMarker
        {
            Symbol = "url(/Proj/images/cross.png)"
        }
    };
}
```

In runtime I get: `A first chance exception of type 'System.ArrayTypeMismatchException' occurred in App_Web_pz3kxbru.dll`

I found a fix doing this to create `result`:

```
Object[] result = new object[tmp.Count];
for (int j = 0; j < tmp.Count; j++)
{
      result [j] = new object[] { (DateTime)tmp[j].Row["DATE"],
                                    Convert.ToDouble(tmp[j].Row["VALUE"])};
}
```

Now everything works fine. However I don't have any clue of what actually I did... Can you please explain me the difference between the methods I used to obtain `result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>The only difference I can notice is, `Convert.ToDouble` in the first approach :</s>

```
.Select(row => new Object[] { row.Field<DateTime>("DATE"),
                                            Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<string>("VALUE"))})
```

<s>versus `Convert.ToInt32` in the second :</s>

```
new object[] { (DateTime)tmp[j].Row["DATE"],
                                    Convert.ToInt32(tmp[j].Row["VALUE"])};
```

**UPDATE :**

The first approach create a new array, replacing the original array which is array of object (`Object[]`) with new array which is 'array of array' (`Object[][]`), hence causes a problem ([co-variant array problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104268/cant-convert-value-type-array-to-params-object)).

The second approach doesn't create a new array, but fill in each slot in the original array of object with an array. So in this case, `result` is still array of object, doesn't get changed to 'array of array', hence can avoid exception.

If you favor the LINQ approach, this will do (still need a counter variable) :

```
Object[] result = new object[tmp.Count];
int i = 0;
result = tmp.Table
            .AsEnumerable()
            .ForEach(row => result[i++] = new Object[] { row.Field<DateTime>("DATE"),
                                            Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<string>("VALUE"))});
```

or better yet, simply cast the array of object to object :

```
result = tmp.Table
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(row => (Object)new Object[] { row.Field<DateTime>("DATE"),
                                            Convert.ToDouble(row.Field<string>("VALUE"))})
            .ToArray();
```

Comment: sorry was it was a "typo". The exception arises when code gets to the point of modifying `result`. So you think that both methods produce the same output?

Comment: after reading the question again, nope both approach act differently. The first returning a new array because of using `.ToArray()`, and unfortunately the new array is not array of object but can be assign to variable of type array of object (both type are co-variant).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I slowly start to understand, maybe... Per my current understanding, I see both the `result` as array with objects[] inside each item.

 I understand that the first method replaces `result` with a new array (in fact `object[tmp.Count]` is not needed in the definition, and without it I have the same result).

What I'm still a bit confused about is why it's replaced with something different. You mentioned array of array, so it's that the output from the linq notation I used?

Comment: Oh didn't see the edit. Thanks again. Also for the `co-variant array problem` link.