# Why IEnumerable not equivalent to list

Tags: c#

When I write this code it allow me

```
IEnumerable<object> creator = new List<string>();
```

But when I write

```
IEnumerable<object> creator = new List<int>();
```

it shows **compile time error**:

> Error CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable'. An explicit
>   conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I don't know why it is happening.

Comment: You can use ICollection instead of IEnumerable.

Comment: For me first case compiler error too !?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9104268/cant-convert-value-type-array-to-params-object

Answer (score 5):

That's because [value types do not support co-/contravariance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12454794/why-covariance-and-contravariance-do-not-support-value-type).

`string` is a reference type, so it works fine. `int` is a value type, so it doesn't.

You may, however, explicitly convert your list to a list of boxed `int`s:

```
IEnumerable<object> creator = listOfInts.Select(i => (object)i);
```

EDIT:

Contrary to many other answers, value types [do in fact inherit from `object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/object). It's also mentioned in the [struct usage guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-structs). That is *not* the reason for value types being invariant!

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is because int is a value type. although int ultimately does inherit from object, int can not be **inherited from** ;
you can compare their base types with this:

```
Console.WriteLine(10.GetType().BaseType.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("".GetType().BaseType.Name);
```

Comment: yes, and i did point this out. however you can not inherit FROM int. "A struct cannot inherit from another struct or class, and it cannot be the base of a class."